# Como agregar editar un item de un objeto en c#

Tags: c#, while

He tenido que hacer una app en c# para trabajar con Adminpaq, pero me quede atorado en querer agregar el folio al documento, lo que intento es que al resultado de la consulta sql pasarlo a un objeto y este objeto editar un item dentro de este.

Este es mi objeto, todos los campos los lleno de una consulta sql a excepcion del ciddocum01, ese seria el id del documento de adminpaq (adminpaq no maneja autoincrementables, al menos no en vfp)

```
public class Documento
    {
        public int ciddocum01 { get; set; }
        public int ciddocum02 { get; set; }
        public string cseriedo01 { get; set; }
        public string cfolio { get; set; }
        public int cidclien01 { get; set; }
        public string crazonso01 { get; set; }
        public string cfechave01 { get; set; }
        public string cfechapr01 { get; set; }
        public int cidmoneda { get; set; }
        public string ctipocam01 { get; set; }
        public string cobserva01 { get; set; }
        public string cnatural01 { get; set; }
        public int cusaclie01 { get; set; }
        public int cestadoc01 { get; set; }
        public int cneto { get; set; }
        public int cimpuesto1 { get; set; }
        public int cretenci02 { get; set; }
        public int ctotal { get; set; }
        public int cpendiente { get; set; }
        public int cporcent01 { get; set; }
        public string clugarexpe { get; set; }
    }
```

y con esta funcion creo los documentos pendientes

```
public List<object> DocumentosPendientes(string recibo)
        {
            string json = string.Empty;
            List<object> toadmin = new List<object>();
            Documento documento = new Documento();
            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["siete"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string query = "SELECT ciddocum02,cseriedo01, cfolio,idAdmin, crazonso01, cfechave01,cfechapr01,cidmoneda, ctipocam01, cobserva01, cnatural01, cusaclie01 " +
                ", cestadoc01, cneto, cimpuesto1, ISNULL(cretenci02, 0) As cretenci02, ctotal, cpendiente, cporcent01, clugarexpe FROM DocumentosPendientes WHERE IdContraRecibo = @p";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", recibo);
                    using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        toadmin.Clear();
                        int count = 0;
                        
                        
                        while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        count += 1;
                        documento.ciddocum01 = count;
                        documento.ciddocum02 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[0]);
                        documento.cseriedo01 = rd[1].ToString();
                        documento.cfolio = rd[2].ToString();
                        documento.cidclien01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[3]);
                        documento.crazonso01 = rd[4].ToString();
                        documento.cfechave01 = DateTime.Parse(rd[5].ToString());
                        documento.cfechapr01 = DateTime.Parse(rd[6].ToString());
                        documento.cidmoneda = Convert.ToInt32(rd[7]);
                        documento.ctipocam01 = rd[8].ToString();
                        documento.cobserva01 = rd[9].ToString();
                        documento.cnatural01 = rd[10].ToString();
                        documento.cusaclie01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[11]);
                        documento.cestadoc01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[12]);
                        documento.cneto = Convert.ToInt32(rd[13]);
                        documento.cimpuesto1 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[14]);
                        documento.cretenci02 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[15]);
                        documento.ctotal = Convert.ToInt32(rd[16]);
                        documento.cpendiente = Convert.ToInt32(rd[17]);
                        documento.cporcent01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[18]);
                        documento.clugarexpe = rd[19].ToString();
                        toadmin.Add(documento);
                    }

                        
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rd.FieldCount);

                        return toadmin;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Pero al agregar en el while

```
count += 1;
```

este simplemente me guarda un 4 dentro del item ciddocum01 cuando deberia ser
1
2
3
4

he intentando hacerlo con

```
do 
{

//codigo

} while (rd.Read())
```

pero no toma los datos de la consulta e igualmente me toma el valor 4 (que son las tablas que cumplen con la condicion), si alguien ha trabajado con esto, agradeceria mucho un poco de ayuda, esta es la respuesta que da el api

```
[
  {
    "ciddocum01": 4,
    "ciddocum02": 3013,
    "cseriedo01": "A         ",
    "cfolio": "65445     ",
    "cidclien01": 53,
    "crazonso01": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "cfechave01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cfechapr01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cidmoneda": 1,
    "ctipocam01": "1",
    "cobserva01": "memo",
    "cnatural01": "1   ",
    "cusaclie01": 1,
    "cestadoc01": 1,
    "cneto": 200,
    "cimpuesto1": 16,
    "cretenci02": 0,
    "ctotal": 216,
    "cpendiente": 216,
    "cporcent01": 8,
    "clugarexpe": "xxxxx, Chihu. Mexico"
  },
  {
    "ciddocum01": 4,
    "ciddocum02": 3013,
    "cseriedo01": "A         ",
    "cfolio": "65445     ",
    "cidclien01": 53,
    "crazonso01": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "cfechave01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cfechapr01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cidmoneda": 1,
    "ctipocam01": "1",
    "cobserva01": "memo",
    "cnatural01": "1   ",
    "cusaclie01": 1,
    "cestadoc01": 1,
    "cneto": 200,
    "cimpuesto1": 16,
    "cretenci02": 0,
    "ctotal": 216,
    "cpendiente": 216,
    "cporcent01": 8,
    "clugarexpe": "xxxxxx, Chihu. Mexico"
  },
  {
    "ciddocum01": 4,
    "ciddocum02": 3013,
    "cseriedo01": "A         ",
    "cfolio": "65445     ",
    "cidclien01": 53,
    "crazonso01": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "cfechave01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cfechapr01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cidmoneda": 1,
    "ctipocam01": "1",
    "cobserva01": "memo",
    "cnatural01": "1   ",
    "cusaclie01": 1,
    "cestadoc01": 1,
    "cneto": 200,
    "cimpuesto1": 16,
    "cretenci02": 0,
    "ctotal": 216,
    "cpendiente": 216,
    "cporcent01": 8,
    "clugarexpe": "xxxxx, Chihu. Mexico"
  },
  {
    "ciddocum01": 4,
    "ciddocum02": 3013,
    "cseriedo01": "A         ",
    "cfolio": "65445     ",
    "cidclien01": 53,
    "crazonso01": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "cfechave01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cfechapr01": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
    "cidmoneda": 1,
    "ctipocam01": "1",
    "cobserva01": "memo",
    "cnatural01": "1   ",
    "cusaclie01": 1,
    "cestadoc01": 1,
    "cneto": 200,
    "cimpuesto1": 16,
    "cretenci02": 0,
    "ctotal": 216,
    "cpendiente": 216,
    "cporcent01": 8,
    "clugarexpe": "xxxxxx, Chihu. Mexico"
  }
]
```

Comment: Por mas que tu trabajes con alguna libreria lo tuyo es c# puro. No te entendi el tema de 1 2 3 4, directamente guarda un 4 en lugar de 4 registros? Por otro lado podes evitar usar List<object> deberias realizar List<Documento> y tu metodo igual, le das menos trabajo al procesador

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, al momento de dar la respuesta del api (ya hice la modificacion en la pregunta), me muestra e el campo ciddocum01 un 4, cuando este valor deberia ser autoincrementable

ciddocum01: 1
ciddocum01: 2

Comment: y te muestra los 4 registros identicos o cambia los valores? en tu list toadmin?

Comment: los registros identicos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que tu problema se basa en que estas trabajando con un valor por referencia.

Primero que nada te aconsejo devolver un tipo y no un object, evitas trabajos al procesador con cast.
Segundo: instancia tu clase documento dentro del `while`

```
    public List<Documento> DocumentosPendientes(string recibo)
    {
        string json = string.Empty;
        List<Documento> toadmin = new List<Documento>();
        Documento documento;
        string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["siete"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            string query = "SELECT ciddocum02,cseriedo01, cfolio,idAdmin, crazonso01, cfechave01,cfechapr01,cidmoneda, ctipocam01, cobserva01, cnatural01, cusaclie01 " +
            ", cestadoc01, cneto, cimpuesto1, ISNULL(cretenci02, 0) As cretenci02, ctotal, cpendiente, cporcent01, clugarexpe FROM DocumentosPendientes WHERE IdContraRecibo = @p";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", recibo);
                using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    toadmin.Clear();
                    int count = 0;
                    
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                     documento = new Documento();
                     count++;
                     documento.ciddocum01 = count;
                     documento.ciddocum02 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[0]);
                     documento.cseriedo01 = rd[1].ToString();
                     documento.cfolio = rd[2].ToString();
                     documento.cidclien01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[3]);
                     documento.crazonso01 = rd[4].ToString();
                     documento.cfechave01 = DateTime.Parse(rd[5].ToString());
                     documento.cfechapr01 = DateTime.Parse(rd[6].ToString());
                     documento.cidmoneda = Convert.ToInt32(rd[7]);
                     documento.ctipocam01 = rd[8].ToString();
                     documento.cobserva01 = rd[9].ToString();
                     documento.cnatural01 = rd[10].ToString();
                     documento.cusaclie01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[11]);
                     documento.cestadoc01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[12]);
                     documento.cneto = Convert.ToInt32(rd[13]);
                     documento.cimpuesto1 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[14]);
                     documento.cretenci02 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[15]);
                     documento.ctotal = Convert.ToInt32(rd[16]);
                     documento.cpendiente = Convert.ToInt32(rd[17]);
                     documento.cporcent01 = Convert.ToInt32(rd[18]);
                     documento.clugarexpe = rd[19].ToString();
                    
                     toadmin.Add(documento);
                }

                    
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rd.FieldCount);

                    return toadmin;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Vaya se me habia ido algo como el tipo de lista, pero encerio muchas gracias, me has ayudado mucho!!! y sobre la instancia dentro del while no sabia, no soy mucho de c#, pero me ha servido para manejar lenguajes en desktop